# rails3 thinking-sphinx ERROR: unknown key name 'workers'

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, thinking-sphinx

New 3.2 installation, calling bundle exec rake ts:rebuild, or bundle exec rake ts:index
action fails with error

```
ERROR: unknown key name 'workers' [...] development.sphinx.conf line 13 col 10.
```

the generated file for development.sphinx.conf in states leading to line 13.

```
  workers = threads
```

Upon examination of the file, the only curiosity I have is with regard to the listen port:

```
listen = 127.0.0.1:9310:mysql41
```

and subsequent lines for model indicies call

```
sql_host = localhost
```

Side note.  in deploy.rb
require 'thinking_sphinx/deploy/capistrano'
which is recommended for using ts as a gem fails with error (whereas omitting /deploy deploys):

```
/gems/capistrano-2.14.2/lib/capistrano/configuration/loading.rb:152:in `require': cannot load such file -- thinking_sphinx/deploy/capistrano (LoadError)
```

is this  related?

**Follow-up**

I noticed that workers were introduced as of version 3.  The machine is presently running sphinx v2 for a rails 2.3.10 app.  The comparable sphinx2 files do not invoke workers.  So it appears the app is trying to connect to sphinx2. Is there any way to concurrently run v2 and v3? (note: the Sphinx3 version is running on its own port). Otherwise what are the consequences for the sphinx2 versions, particularly if developed in rails 2 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend upgrading Sphinx to 2.0.6 on your machine, and then use Thinking Sphinx 1.5.0 in your Rails 2.3 apps, and Thinking Sphinx 3.0.3 in your Rails 3.2 apps. You'll need a recent version of Sphinx (which 2.0.6 certainly is) to ensure Sphinx understands the 'workers' setting.

Comment: Someways there... postgre was 9.0.4.  Skipping the hoops that homebrew 0.9.4 made me go through, the 2.3.10 app is up with sphinx 2.0.8. deploy which re-indexes handle sits 30k items properly. searching on pg indicies is OK, but sphinx searches return undefined method `constantize' for 0:Fixnum  on query  ?advanced_search%5Bterms%5D=detrazione

Comment: Have you run a `ts:rebuild` since installing the new Sphinx version?

Comment: daily RTFM moment... no.  ran rebuild, ran index and search is churning out results. Thanx!